# iOS 7 producing random error: JPEG Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00

Tags: ios, html, ipad, uiwebview, jpeg

I have an application which is a wrapper for a digital magazine that is created in html5 / jpg format.

The book is displayed via UIWebView, the book contents is stored locally on the device.

While this works fine on IOS 6 devices and IOS 7 Simulator, on IOS 7 devices i randomly get following errors:

```
<Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00
<Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00
<Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00
```

and a bit later a crash:

```
 <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '***     
-[WebCoreSharedBufferData getBytes:range(inlove): range {0, 4000} exceeds data length 0'
```

When moving thru the pages in the book, the same pages (images) are sometimes displayed correctly and sometimes not at all.

I doubt its a performance issue, because this is happening on IPad 2 as well as iPad 4.

NOTE: the html app is not the krpano viewer.

Comment: All resources are located in the app's document folderAll resources are located in the app's document folder  This happens not just on one book, but on all books that are loaded into the app btw.

Comment: @idplanter did you come up with this issue?

Comment: Did you eventually find the cause of the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a truly random problem or a problem that happens consistently on random files?

If the latter, I suggest doing a file dump on the first few bytes of the file. You should find a start of image marker FF-DA at the beginning.

If the former, that would be tougher. I would add debugging code that  logs the first few byte values in the file.

That way you can determine if something is wrong with the JPEG or if something is happening in the application.

The easiest problem to solve would be having JPEG files with leading nulls that are sometimes ignored.